# Is there a way to add 'fl' parameter to a Solr query to return all attributes without "_" symbols?

Tags: solr

I want to retrieve all attributes in a query from Apache Solr(9.0.0) which does not have any underscores. what should the fl parameter be to achieve this?

Comment: I believe there is no way for this unless you specifically mention them with fl=names of the field.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti is there no to add regex statement like *[^_]*

Comment: where would you add this regex? did you tried with dynamic field?