# Is there a way to exclude fields in Solr?

Tags: solr

What is the fl parameter I have to use to get all fields in a document except for "field1" in Solr?

Comment: you can mark the fields as stored=false....

Comment: https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to add 'fl' parameter to a Solr query to return all attributes without "\_" symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75094901/is-there-a-way-to-add-fl-parameter-to-a-solr-query-to-return-all-attributes-wi)

Comment: There is no built-in way to exclude fields based on a pattern, only to include fields based on a regular glob pattern (so no regex or complex filters - only `fl=field_n*me`).

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti I dont find anything in the page that can solve this

Comment: @sidharthsunilkumar, The page is shared to tell you all the possibilities. If it does not have anything means there is no way to achieve this except what Mats shared in the earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

Right now is not possible to define, in the fl parameter, the fields to exclude from the results. You have to define all the fields you want and not put `field1` in the list. Another possibility is using the regex syntax, as you can see from the official documentation: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/common-query-parameters.html#fl-field-list-parameter

A different solution can be to not store the field in Solr, this possibility clearly depends on your field usage.